# Click the data retrieved after While loop and getting extra information again from database

Tags: php

Here is my problem for your help.

1. Using while loop, I extracted 'name' and 'designation' of all the employees from a database table (using php script)
2. The html shows the retrieved data as a list.
3. I tagged the 'name' data with href link inside php script that is inside while loop.
   For now my intention is when I click each 'name' link, I must get the rest of the information like 'qualification', 'Dt of birth','current_work' etc etc from the database of that particular 'name'.

Can you please help me or refer to any example online?

Comment: Pass id in the link so that you can retrieve the info based on that id on the page it links to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you asked, pass the person's name(or whatever is your primary key) or what so ever in the link, and in the page that fetches the details, use the person's name/your primary key to fetch the details.

**EDIT:**

For example give the link to the person's name like:

```
<a href="yoursite.com/getdetails.php?key=yourkey">Name</a>
```

Replace yourkey with whatever you want to pass as primarykey. And in the `getdetails.php` use the key you just received and fetch the data from the database.

**EDIT-2**

You can fetch the key in the `getdetails.php` by using `$_GET["key"]`